# html - Duas scrollbars verticais no Android

Tags: html, android, css, html5

As Custom Scrollbars e a scrollbar padrão do Chrome estão em conflito, devido ao **height:100vh**. Mas acho que o Chrome detecta como se **100vh** fosse equivalente ao numero de pixels Y do Android, e não o da WebView.

Enfim, eu quero que o site fique em 100% da tela do Chrome Canary, assim removendo a scrollbar padrão como na foto [1].

Mas há um porém, a minha tela é MaxVision, e muitos valores ficaram incomatíveis com a minha tela um deles é a dpi.

No StackOverflow eu vi uma pergunta relacionada, porém na minha tela não deu certo.

**Eis o código HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
  </body>
</html>
```

No código acima, fiz com que o conteúdo da página fosse maior que a minha tela.

**O erro deve estar aqui:**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin:0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track { 
    background-color: #000; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    background-color:#0f0;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
}

}
body {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height:calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

[image: a scrollbar está em conflito]

Só quero um jeito de ficar a scrollbar horizontal  dentro da tela

Comment: Tem como vc colocar um print?

Comment: Espere um minuto, mas acho que vai ficar meio difícil de ver.

Comment: Tudo certo agora @Sam

Comment: Vc tentou trocar 100vh por 100% para ver se resolve? e esse calc(100vh - 50px) pq fez isso??

Comment: Eu só fiz um teste, e também não deu certo, mas ficou menor. E quanto melhor a compatibilidade melhor.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, vc está se referindo àquela barra invisível padrão que só aparece quando faz scroll, não é?

Comment: Exato (infelizmente o comentário deve ser maior)

Comment: Cara não sei se te interessa essa opção, mas esse plugin de jQuery é bem legal e super customizável e crossbrowser. Ele remove a scrollbar original do browser, e faz outra com javascript, funciona muito bem! No seu carro ele vai remover todas as scrollbars e vc vai construir uma nova com esse plugin https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/

Comment: Testando aqui no Bluestacks essa barra não aparece, só a vermelha.

Comment: Ok, se tiver como passar o codigo e a saída for a mesma

Comment: Me parece que até esse Nicescroll tem o mesmo problema, dê uma olhada na scrollbar deles

Comment: Caro Edu, no titulo vc fala uma coisa e na pergunta fala outra, afinal o que deseja? O problema é que aparece 2 scrollbars, quer que apareça apenas um? Ou é o contrário? É um problema de espaçamento? Por favor edite a sua pergunta a torna-la clara para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Quero que remova a Scrollbar padrão, e o problema tem haver com o height, pois o scroller horizontal esta abaixo da pagina que seria 100vh. como pode ver, existe uma scrollbar horizontal abaixo da pagina que devido ao scroller padrão e pelo width, ele não aparece amenos que role 2 ou 3 vezes no Android

Comment: Com calma edu, tirando a parte toda que você já explicou, responda ao que eu perguntei exatamente, se não fica dificil ajudar, você quer ou não 2 scrollbars? Independente de serem customizados ou não;

Comment: Não, quero apenas os modificados, desculpe a demora

Comment: Voce pode tirar a barra de rolagem do seu navegador , e usar o nicescroll

http://www.lucianosimas.com.br/blog/tirar-barra-de-rolagem-do-navegador/

https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/how-to-use/

Acho que daria certo, ou tirar somente do mobile usando as media queries do css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulei o mesmo problema, na qual eu ficava com duas barras de scroll

A solução é :

Use o [NiceScroll](https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/how-to-use/)

e faça o scroll desejado, é bem simples de usar, e não é pesado.

Aqui vai um exemplo de código para você ter um norte :

```
 <script>
    $("body").niceScroll({
      cursorcolor:"coral",
      cursorwidth:"10px",
      cursorborder:"none",
      horizrailenabled:false

    });

    </script>
```

Este código deixará seu scroll em coral e não aparecerá o scroll horizontal.

Após colocar pra funcionar o NiceScroll ele ainda estará dando o erro que você está tendo

a solução é colocar em todos os seus CSS, tanto no principal (Style) como no responsivo(Caso Tiver)

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden; }
```

Assim, só será exibido o Nicescroll, não aparecendo mais o padrão

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]